# How to add the empty values for the non required inputs if the user skip the fields in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react js I have registration form if you fill all the fields then only the data is storing in database so now I need to add the empty values for the non required inputs if the user skip those fields.

Please help me to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Use components setState method. Can't help you more since you didn't share any code

Comment: welcome to stack-overflow, a [mcve] would help

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide an example of your case I'm assuming you are only saving the filled inputs to state.

You can define a default object like:

```
const DEFAULT_OBJECT = { title: "", email: "" };
```

and afterwards merge your fields with the default object:

```
const submitObject = {
  ...DEFAULT_OBJECT,
  ...whateverFieldsYouHave
};
```